# Программа работает только с определённым количеством переменных, с остальными - не выводит ответ пользователю

Tags: c++

Есть задача: определить, попадает ли введённая координата в окружность заданного радиуса или же нет. При вводе ординаты >2 программа не выводит результат. В чём проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const float RADIUS = 1.5;
const float A = -0.2;
bool BelongsCircle(float, float);
int main()
{
float XPoint, YPoint;
cout<<"Введите кординаты X и Y"<<endl;
cin>>XPoint>>YPoint;
if (BelongsCircle(XPoint, YPoint))
 if (XPoint<=A)
  {
  cout<<"OK"<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
  cout<<"Missing"<< endl;
  }
  return 0;
  }
  bool BelongsCircle(float x,float y)
  {
  return x * x + y * y <= pow(RADIUS,2);
  }
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы определить, " попадает ли введённая координата в область ограниченную окружностью заданного радиуса или принадлежит ей ",  нужно, чтобы выполнялось условие (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2 <= R^2 Т.е, нужен радиус и 2 пары координат. const float RADIUS = 1.5;, cin>>XPoint>>YPoint; - радиус и одна пара есть. Где координаты центра и что такое const float A = -0.2;?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте просто добавим отступы в ваш код, что делает любой не совсем тупой редактор...

```
if (BelongsCircle(XPoint, YPoint))
    if (XPoint<=A)
    {
        cout<<"OK"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Missing"<< endl;
    }
```

Итак, что мы видим? что если `BelongsCircle(XPoint, YPoint)` истинно, то какой-то вывод будет (который зависит от `XPoint`). А если ложно — никакой ветви `else` не предусмотрено, ничего выведено не будет.

Зачем у вас вообще проверка `if (XPoint<=A)`?

Comment: Хотите угадаю? Он решает задачу типа: "Определите, принадлежит ли точка заштрихованной области".